# How to convert a string to a plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

[image]

I am trying to implement a Mongo query. I wrote a function that returns one of the query's parameters:

```
"'Week Of': {'$in': [02/13/17]}"
```

I don't want the double quotes at the front and the back of the string. I understand it is a string and it needs it, but when I inject it into my query, it will not work because it has those double quotes. Is there any way to convert the string to a plain text so it would only be

```
'Week Of': {'$in': [02/13/17]}
```

I have a model that accepts a hash in the middle like:

```
Nosql.aggregate([ p_header + ", " + s_header], {args[0]}, table.target_collection.name.to_sym)
```

The second argument is:

```
args[0] = "'Week Of': {'$in': [02/13/17]}"
```

This doesn't work. However, when I manually put in

```
'Week Of': {'$in': [02/13/17]}
```

in place of

```
args[0]
```

it works.

Comment: Show your code.  Also, the double quotes are unlikely in the string -- they just show up when you display a string to indicate it is a string.

Comment: updated @dbugger

Comment: Are you sure your args[0] is "'Week Of': {'$in': [02/13/17]}", because that is what a string will look like in the console.

Comment: If this second argument of Nosql.aggregate expecting a hash or bson or something else?

Comment: added a pic. The second argument is expecting a mongodb query

Comment: Don't use a picture to display information essential to the question. We can't reuse the information without typing it in, and search engines can't index it. Instead copy and paste the information into the question, formatting it appropriately for readability.

Comment: You can't change a string into plain text, because it already is. A String is an array of bytes we perceive as text. According to the [String documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html): "A String object holds and manipulates an arbitrary sequence of bytes, typically representing characters."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it wants a hash, which when you enter it in works. But Ruby doesn't parse it the same way when you place a string argument in the curly brackets like you are trying to do. You could do something with eval, but it is simpler to have your function that generates the argument to return a hash, not a string.

You don't show that code but you want something like this...

```
def make_my_hash(dates)
  return {"Week of" => { "$in" => dates}}
end
```

then change your call to...

```
Nosql.aggregate([ p_header + ", " + s_header], args[0], table.target_collection.name.to_sym)
```